# How to save document id in the document field in android Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to save the document to the firestore, but I also want to save the document id of the newly saved as well to the same document, I am trying the below example but not good

```
 String id = db.collection("user_details").document().getId();

                                Map map = new HashMap<>();
                               map.put("username", username);
                                map.put("email", email);
                                map.put("id", id);




                                UserRef.document(id).set(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                        //progressbar invisible;
;

                                    }
                                });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you call `document()`, you're going to get a new unique ID.  So, be sure to call it only once, so you only deal with one ID.

First get the DocumentReference:

```
DocumentReference ref = db.collection("user_details").document();
```

Get its ID:

```
String id = ref.getId();
```

Then compose the data to send:

```
Map map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("username", username);
map.put("email", email);
map.put("id", id);
```

And finally, put that data in the document referenced earlier:

```
ref.set(map)...
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to save your ID in a document first you need to creat one. Problem is that ID is created at the same time as a document is created. But we can first create ID and than send our document like this:

```
val matchRef = mFirestore.collection(FirebaseHelp().USERS).document(user.uid).collection(FirebaseHelp().MATCHES).document() //notice this will not create document it will just create reference so we can get our new id from it
val newMatchId = matchRef.id //this is new uniqe id from firebase like "8tmitl09F9rL87ej27Ay"
```

The document is not yet created we just have a new id so now we add this id to our POJO class (or it is POKO I guess because it is Kotlin).

```
class MatchInfo(
        var player1Name: String? = null,
        var player2Name: String? = null,
        var player3Name: String? = null,
        var player4Name: String? = null,
        var firebaseId: String? = null, //this is new added string for our New ID
)
```

So now we create our object we want to upload to firebase:

```
val matchInfo = MatchInfo(player1?.mName, player2?.mName, player3?.mName, player4?.mName, newMatchId)
```

or we set our new id just before sending the object to firebase

```
matchInfo.firebaseId = newMatchId
```

and now we send our object to firebase with our new ID like this:

```
val matches = mFirestore.collection(FirebaseHelp().USERS).document(user.uid).collection(FirebaseHelp().MATCHES)
matches.document(newMatchId).set(matchInfo) // this will create new document with name like"8tmitl09F9rL87ej27Ay" and that document will have field "firebaseID" with value "8tmitl09F9rL87ej27Ay"
```